# Spring Web Flow - do objects in flow scope need their methods synchronized?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

From Web Flow sample Booking application:

```
<on-start>
    <evaluate expression="bookingService.createBooking(hotelId, currentUser.name)" result="flowScope.booking" />
</on-start>
```

When I am setting values to the flowScope.booking object in view states of the flow, how is this synchronized? Couldn't there be a problem with memory visibility, as each request accessing flowScope.booking might be served by different thread?

EDIT: I am not talking about multiple concurrent requests trying to modify same object. I am talking about two subsequent requests working with same object in the flow scope.

Is it correct, that each of these requests might be served by different thread by the container?

How is it ensured, that when first request (handled by thread A) sets checkoutDate property of booking to some value and second request (handled by thread B) can then read checkoutDate property of booking object and actually get the value, which was set by thread A?

If you don't know, what I'm talking about, please see: https://www.cs.umd.edu/users/pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html

There should be some synchronization mechanism. But I don't know, if it is somewhere in Spring framework, or if it should be done by me - making all getters and setters of domain objects synchronized?

Comment: Why would there be multiple concurrent request modifying the same object? It is bound to flow scope, which is stored in the session so is only available to a single user and not between users.

Comment: I've extended the original question. I'll be happy for explanation.

Comment: In theory webflow should prevent that, the first request will succeed the second will fail (if configured correctly). So if you have configured webflow correctly this should not happen, when it happens you can have race conditions but this should be exceptional and the normal case, so making everything synchronized 'just to be sure' isn't the right way to go.